# How to get WORKSPACE directory in bazel rule

Tags: bazel

I order to use clang tools like `clang-format`, `clang-tidy` or generate a [compilation database](https://sarcasm.github.io/notes/dev/compilation-database.html) like [this](https://github.com/Grailbio/bazel-compilation-database), I need to know the WORKSPACE directory within the .bzl file. How can I obtain it? Consider the following example where I just want to print the full path of all the src files in my workspace:

`# simple_example.bzl`

```
def _impl(ctx):
  workspace_dir = // ---> what comes here? <---
  command = "\n".join([echo %s/%s" % (workspace_dir, f.short_path) 
                       for f in ctx.files.srcs])

  ctx.actions.write(
      output=ctx.outputs.executable,
      content=command,
      is_executable=True)


echo_full_path = rule(
    implementation=_impl,
    executable=True,
    attrs={
      "srcs": attr.label_list(allow_files=True),
    }
)
```

`# BUILD`

```
echo_full_path(
    name = "echo",
    srcs = glob(["src/**/*.cc"])
)
```

Is there a cleaner/nicer way of doing this?

Comment: What you have now should result in a script that will contain the paths of the files relative to the workspace, so the script will work only if it's executed from the workspace root. Are you trying to get around that limitation? I imagine that the workspace directory isn't available in skylark rule impls simply because there hasn't been a need yet, but also that it would make it easier to write rules that don't work with remote execution or that would pollute artifact caches.

Comment: @ahumesky yes, that is what I am trying. You're right that would contradict the the intention of remote execution (I guess artifact caches would not be needed here), but in this case it would make things a lot easier, since looking for source files is very simple with bazel. Furthermore, I'd like to do everything with just one tool, so that the user does not have to switch between different tools. I guess I'll have to implement this with a simple shell script. If you want you can post an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably get around this by using `realpath`. Something like:

```py
def _impl(ctx):

  ctx.actions.run_shell(
    inputs = ctx.files.srcs,
    outputs = [ctx.outputs.executable],
    command = "\n".join(["echo echo $(realpath \"%s\") >> %s" % (f.path,
              ctx.outputs.executable.path) for f in ctx.files.srcs]),
    execution_requirements = {
        "no-sandbox": "1",
        "no-cache": "1",
        "no-remote": "1",
        "local": "1",
    },
  )

echo_full_path = rule(
    implementation=_impl,
    executable=True,
    attrs={
      "srcs": attr.label_list(allow_files=True),
    }
)
```

Note the `execution_requirements` to get around the potential issues in my comment above.

Answer (score 3):

I modified @ahumesky's rule to implicitly use the `BUILD` file as the source and to write only the workspace directory once:

**workspace.bzl**

```py
def _write_workspace_dir_impl(ctx):
    src = ctx.files._src[0]
    out = ctx.actions.declare_file(ctx.label.name)
    ctx.actions.run_shell(
        inputs = ctx.files._src,
        outputs = [out],
        command = """
          full_path="$(readlink -f -- "{src_full}")"
          # Trim the src.short_path suffix from full_path. Double braces to
          # output literal brace for shell.
          echo "${{full_path%/{src_short}}}" >> {out_full}
        """.format(src_full = src.path, src_short = src.short_path, out_full = out.path),
        execution_requirements = {
            "no-sandbox": "1",
            "no-remote": "1",
            "local": "1",
        },
    )
    return [DefaultInfo(files = depset([out]))]

write_workspace_dir = rule(
    implementation = _write_workspace_dir_impl,
    attrs = {
        "_src": attr.label(allow_files = True, default = "BUILD"),
    },
    doc = "Writes the full path of the current workspace dir to a file.",
)
```

**BUILD**

```py
load(":workspace.bzl", "write_workspace_dir")

write_workspace_dir(
    name = "workspace_dir",
)
```

**Sample output**

```sh
bazel build //build/bazel:workspace_dir
INFO: Analyzed target //build/bazel:workspace_dir 
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action

cat bazel-bin/build/bazel/workspace_dir
/p/$MY_PROJECT
```

Comment: In 2023 this is the solution that works

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me and writing a `repository_rule` instead of a regular one, resolving the following label can help you: `"@//:WORKSPACE"`

Then use `ctx.path` to extract the required data: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#path

Comment: If you are writing a repository_rule, you could as well pass the `__workspace_dir__` variable from `WORKSAPCE.bazel` file.