# Bazel: relative local path as url in http_archive()

Tags: c++, bazel

I am trying to include an external library into my Bazel project.
It is a commercial, closed source software library that comes as a bunch of `.h` and `.a` files in a tar file (Linux). There is no public download link, you have to download the archive manually somewhere.

Thus, I checked the library archives into Git (let's not discuss this here) in `vendor/` and use

```py
http_archive(
    name = "library_name",
    build_file = "//third_party:library_name.BUILD",
    sha256 = "12165fbcbac............",
    urls = ["file:///home/myuser/git/repo/vendor/libraryname.tar.gz"],
)
```

I would like to not use an absolute path in `urls=`, so my coworkers can checkout and build the library without hassle. How can I use a relative path with `http_archive()`?

I have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545575/how-to-get-workspace-directory-in-bazel-rule), but it seems to be not exactly the same problem and the example is incomplete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very simple [custom repository rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/repository_rules.html) can do that for you. [repository_ctx.extract](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#extract) does all the heavy lifting. I wrote this up just now as a barebones example:

```py
def _test_archive_impl(repository_ctx):
  repository_ctx.extract(repository_ctx.attr.src)
  repository_ctx.file("BUILD.bazel", repository_ctx.read(repository_ctx.attr.build_file))

test_archive = repository_rule(
    attrs = {
        "src": attr.label(mandatory = True, allow_single_file = True),
        "build_file": attr.label(mandatory = True, allow_single_file = True),
    },
    implementation = _test_archive_impl,
)
```

For your basic use case, you might not need any changes to that (besides a better name). Adding the ability to pass [stripPrefix](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#extract.stripPrefix) through would be straightforward. Depending on your use case, `build_file_contents` like other rules have instead of `build_file` might be useful too.

For reference, here's the `WORKSPACE` I used for testing (the rule definition above was in `test.bzl`):

```py
load("//:test.bzl", "test_archive")

test_archive(
    name = "test_repository",
    src = "//:test.tar.gz",
    build_file = "//:test.BUILD",
)
```

As an alternative to all of that, you could just check in the files from the archive and then use [new_local_repository](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#new_local_repository) instead. Easier to work with in some ways, harder in others.